# Powershell piping first line of list

Tags: powershell, encoding, pipe

I want to convert some tiff's into multipage tiff with powershell and [nconvert](https://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/NConvert_User_Guide).
I started script with

> powershell script.ps1 \Path\to\tiffs

Content of script.ps1 is

```
$path=$args[0]
$File = dir $path\*.tif | foreach {$_.name}
$File | Out-File debug.txt
nconvert.exe -overwrite -o binder.tiff -multi -out tiff -c 7 -l $File
```

And get error only for the first first line of `$File`! 
My hypotesis, the first line has an BOM. Now my question is How can I convert my $File variable into ansi, or utf8 without BOM?

Comment: As currently written, `nconvert.exe` does not  refer to  the `debug.txt` file. Hence, its encoding does not matter. However,  [`Out-File` cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821839) has a parameter `-Encoding` (at least version from 3.0 and higher). The `$File` variable is an array of strings in memory and as such it _does not_ contain a BOM.

Comment: @JosefZ If `$File` does not contain BOM, why `nconvert` does not want to open first line?

Comment: Again, the `$File` variable is **an array of strings in memory** and as such it  can't contain a BOM.  Please explain the `…  -l $File` in your code. What the `-l` parameter  stands for?

Comment: @JosefZ As mention in `-help` the `-l`: `-l file : Use file as filelist`

Comment: Then use `$File | Out-File debug.txt -Encoding Default` (`Default` uses the encoding that corresponds to the **system's active code page** i.e. ANSI encoding) and then `… -l debug.txt`

Comment: because $File is not a File containing a FileList, Debug.txt is. $File is an array in memory. In your nconvert command replace $File with (full path to debug.txt)

Comment: As a sidenote, you are capturing the file NAMES only `$_.name`. I think it would be better to have a file containing the FULL filenames, including path: `$_.FullName`. Otherwise, how does nconvert know where to look for these files?